# How do you make each option in a drop down menu a link with the association simple_form call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hyperlink, simple-form

I have this form using the simple_form plugin:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@video, @video.comments.new], :remote => true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :comment_title, :collection => @video.comment_titles, :label => "Comment Title:", :include_blank => false %>
  <%= f.input :body, :label => false, :placeholder => "Post a comment." %>
  <%= f.button :submit, :value => "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

and this creates a drop down list with this line:

```
<%= f.association :comment_title, :collection => @video.comment_titles, :label => "Comment Title:", :include_blank => false %>
```

My question is how do you modify this code so that each drop down item is a link to each `comment_title`'s individual show view?

UPDATE

Here is the generated html from the code from the first answer:

```
<select class="select optional" id="comment_comment_title_id" name="comment[comment_title_id]">
    <option value="&lt;a href=" comment_titles="" 224"="">#&lt;CommentTitle:0x10353b890&gt;"&gt;#&lt;CommentTitle:0x10353b890&gt;</option>
    <option value="&lt;a href=" comment_titles="" 225"="">#&lt;CommentTitle:0x1035296e0&gt;"&gt;#&lt;CommentTitle:0x1035296e0&gt;</option>
    <option value="&lt;a href=" comment_titles="" 226"="">#&lt;CommentTitle:0x1035295a0&gt;"&gt;#&lt;CommentTitle:0x1035295a0&gt;</option>    
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually figured it out. Here is the ruby code:

```
<%= f.association :comment_title, :collection => @video.comment_titles.map {|ct| [ct.title, comment_title_path(ct)] }, :label => "Comment Title:", :include_blank => false %>
```

This passes the first element in the array as the text, and the second element in the array as the value. Then I use this jQuery code:

```
$("select").change(function () {
      var url = $("select option:selected").val();
      $(location).attr("href",url);
});
```

Pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

try `:collection => @video.comment_titles.map {|ct| [ct, (link_to ct, comment_title_path(ct))] }`

Comment: oh didn't know that was even possible... i was going to use javascript but this is cleaner... i'll try this out

Comment: one question though... why is there `ct` in the first element of the array before the link?

Comment: well, the first element is suppossed to be an option value: <option value="comment title">Link to Comment Title</option>

Comment: this isn't correct. i've posted the generated html from your code in the question details. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: i figured it out. Check my answer.