# Return a number from collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I am using an input field with a collection, which is drawn from an array in the model. This works well, but I would like to return a different value to the actual column in the table. I'm using **simple_form**.

**model**

```
TASK_OPTIONS = %w(Detection Cloning Sequencing Primer_List Primer_Check)
```

**view**

```
<%= f.input :primer_task, :collection => Primer3Batch::TASK_OPTIONS, :label => 'Task' %>
```

I might want to return something like this:

```
{1 => 'Detection', 2 => 'Cloning'... etc
```

Or this:

```
{'AB' => 'Detection, 'C' => 'Cloning' ....
```

That is: the page will display **Detection, Cloning** etc but the database column will store **1,2** or **AB, C**
I've guessed it can be done with a hash but I can't quite work out the syntax.

Comment: Similar question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720474/how-do-you-make-each-option-in-a-drop-down-menu-a-link-with-the-association-simp?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = []
%w(Detection Cloning Sequencing Primer_List Primer_Check).each.with_index(1) do |it,ind|
    a << [ind,it]
end
Hash[a]
# => {1=>"Detection",
#     2=>"Cloning",
#     3=>"Sequencing",
#     4=>"Primer_List",
#     5=>"Primer_Check"}
```

Using `Enumerable#each_with_object`

```
a = %w(Detection Cloning Sequencing Primer_List Primer_Check)
a.each_with_object({}) {|it,h| h[a.index(it) + 1 ] = it }
# => {1=>"Detection",
#     2=>"Cloning",
#     3=>"Sequencing",
#     4=>"Primer_List",
#     5=>"Primer_Check"}
```

Comment: Wow that looks great. So that creates the hash, but what needs to be done from the view end to display the item and save the index?